# If $\int\frac{\left( x^2+1 \right) e^x }{ (x+1)^2}dx = f(x)e^x + C $ , find $f(x)$

Tags: integration, derivatives

My Question:

> If $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\left( x^2+1 \right) e^x }{ (x+1)^2}dx = f(x)e^x + C $ , find $f(x)$

Here is my attempt:

The integrand needs to be split into two functions $f(x)e^x$ and $g(x)e^x$ such that $f(x)+g(x)=\frac{\left( x^2+1 \right)}{(x+1)^2}$ and $g(x)=f'(x)$. 
I assumed that the functions would be of the form $A(x)\over(x+1)$ and $B(x)\over(x+1)^2$ respectively since the derivative of the former would have $(x+1)^2$ in its denominator.
From this, we get, $$(x+1)A(x)+B(x)=x^2+1$$ and $$(x+1)A'(x)-A(x)=B(x)$$
Solving these we can get $$xA(x)+(x+1)A'(x)=x^2+1$$
This is where I got stuck. Is my approach correct? If yes, what am I missing?

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: @MartinR Okay, I'll keep that in mind. And yes, that does answer my question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Assume that $A(x)$ is polynomial

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu That solved my problem, thank you so much!